# "Order by"  result of  "group by" count?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, sql-order-by

This query

```
Message.where("message_type = ?", "incoming").group("sender_number").count
```

will return me an hash.

```
OrderedHash {"1234"=>21, "2345"=>11, "3456"=>63, "4568"=>100}
```

Now I want to order by count of each group. How can I do that within the query.

Answer (score 139, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is to just add an order clause to the original query. If you give the count method a specific field, it will generate an output column with the name count_{column}, which can be used in the sql generated by adding an order call:

```
Message.where('message_type = ?','incoming')
       .group('sender_number')
       .order('count_id asc').count('id')
```

Comment: Which database engine are you using? Which version of rails, and what's the generated sql? I've just got a test case (different model) working fine on rails 3.0.7... e.g. `@test = Price.where('price is not null').group(:price_date).order('count_price asc').count('price')`, which generates `SELECT COUNT("prices"."price") AS count_price, price_date AS price_date FROM "prices" WHERE (price is not null) GROUP BY price_date ORDER BY count_price asc`

Comment: Thank you so much for this. This saved me so much time off my query compared to how I was doing it before! Most important lesson: I learned that the count method 'will generate an output column with the name count_{column}'! Thank you!

Comment: I can't believe this only has 35 (now 36) upvotes. So useful!

Comment: Might be worth specifying whcih DB we're using here. 
This doesn't work for Postgres. whereas @penner's below does.

Comment: Thanks Simon. Superb!

Comment: As of Rails 4+ with PostgreSQL: `Message.where(message_type: "incoming").group(:sender_number).order("count(*)").count`

Comment: Rails 5 with PostgreSQL: `Message.where(message_type: "incoming").group(:sender_number).order(:count_all).count`

Comment: Rails 5 with MySQL: `Message.where(message_type: "incoming").group(:sender_number).order("count(*)").count`

Answer (score 20):

When I tried this, rails gave me this error

```
SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: count_id: SELECT  COUNT(*) AS count_all, state AS state FROM "ideas"  GROUP BY state ORDER BY count_id desc LIMIT 3
```

Notice that it says SELECT ... AS count_all

So I updated the query from @Simon's answer to look like this and it works for me

```
.order('count_all desc')
```

Comment: Not sure which AR version causes it to use `count_all` instead of `count_id` but in 4.2.1, `.order("count_id desc")` works.

Comment: Works for me. Maybe you missed the .count('id')?