# Active Record order by group size

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I've got an active record query where I'm using group_by

```
@foo = Foo.group_by(&:relation)
```

Then in the view i'm using

```
@foo.each do |group, values|
 group x has values.count elements
end
```

Is there a way I could sort these by the count of each group?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

group_by is not a ActiveRecord method, group is. group_by is a Enumerator method.

What about

```
@foo = Foo.group('relation').order('count_id asc').count('id')
```

Taken from ["Order by"  result of  "group by" count?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7131109/order-by-result-of-group-by-count).

Otherwise, if you want to sort it on Ruby level, you could do

```
disordered_hash = {:two=>[1, 2], :one=>[1], :three=>[1, 2, 3]}
ordered_array = disordered_hash.sort {|k, v| k[1].count <=> v[1].count} # add .reverse if you want
# => [[:one, [1]], [:two, [1, 2]], [:three, [1, 2, 3]]]
```

Comment: undefined method `order' for #<Hash:0xc03dd68>

Comment: what if you change group_by to group ? Edited my answer.

Comment: That would work, I'll give it to you.
Though I believe that's doing its grouping on the db level, whereas the other was giving me things I could iterate over in ruby.

Comment: +1. But I'd like to add that for the pure-ruby version you can just pass the result right into `Hash#[]` to get your ordered results a an actual hash again. Following the code example here, you could add one final step: `ordered_hash = Hash[ordered_array]`. And the console output will now show `=> {:one=>[1], :two=>[1, 2], :three=>[1, 2, 3]}`.